# Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect - Java Springboot app

Tags: java, spring-boot, certificate, keystore, keytool

I know this question has been asked multiple times but I still can't seem to get around it. I'm trying to connect to `Azure-SQL` db from my SpringBoot app and keep running into this error :

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:783) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Password verification failed
```

I've a rapidssl.jks file that I'm adding to the app's VM args to get past something similar to ["PKIX path building failed" and "unable to find valid certification path to requested target"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076179/pkix-path-building-failed-and-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requ)

I'm on `MacBook` and have tried to create a self signed certificate using:

```
sudo keytool -export -keystore rapidssl-36.1.2.jks -file selfsign.crt
```

and importing it using:  `sudo keytool -import -keystore "cacerts" -file "/Users/Documents/cert/selfsign.crt" -alias rapidssl` running in `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security` directory. I completed those steps but still can't get past the error. Any suggestions/recommendations?

I'm on Java 8 (zulu jdk), SpringBoot: 2.0.4-RELEASE, MacBook OS Catalina 10.15.7

Answer (score 1):

The quotes in your command seem to be the issue:

```
sudo keytool -import -keystore "cacerts" -file "/.../selfsign.crt" ...
```

The keystore **`cacerts`**, as well as the **`file`** shouldn't be in between quotes.

You already execute it on the right path (*jre/lib/security*), so try this:

```
sudo keytool -import -keystore cacerts -file /.../selfsign.crt -alias rapidssl
```

---

*An example of the keytool command:*

[image]

Comment: I get certificate already exists under the alias message followed by Do you still want to add it? I input yes and it said certificate aded to keystore but the error remains.

Answer (score 1):

Add all of the below properties:

1. server.ssl.key-store
2. server.ssl.key-store-type=JKS
3. server.ssl.key-store-password
4. server.ssl.key-alias
5. server.ssl.key-password

Comment: thanks for your answer, please edit and add more details, for example where these properties should be added into. That would complete the answer and guide in fixing the issue.